# How to make a table with no cells-per-row defined only with CSS

Tags: html, css

I was looking for a solution to make a table, *using `<table>` element*, with **no *cells-per-row* defined**.

*`<tr>`* elements must behave like *`<td>`*, and keeping using *`<td>`s*, the result will be a horizontal table like so:
`Tr 1 - Td1` `Tr 2 - Td1` `Tr 3 - Td1` `Tr 4 - Td1` `Tr 5 - Td1` `Tr 6 - Td1`
`Tr 7 - Td1` `Tr 8 - Td1` `Tr 9 - Td1` `Tr … - Td1` `Tr … - Td1` `Tr … - Td1`
And then if the page is resized the result will be:

`Tr 1 - Td1` `Tr 2 - Td1` `Tr 3 - Td1` `Tr 4 - Td1`
`Tr 5 - Td1` `Tr 6 - Td1` `Tr 7 - Td1` `Tr 8 - Td1`
`Tr 9 - Td1` `Tr … - Td1` `Tr … - Td1` `Tr … - Td1`
How can I achieve it ***only with *`CSS`**** ?

Comment: Please post answer's code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!! I found my answer on http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

It is a table with no cells-per-row *`<td>`* defined because each "cell" is a *`<tr>`*, and if you try to resize the window, the number of cells-per-row changes.

They used this little `CSS` style to achieve this:

```
tr {display: inline-block;}
```

Here's the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block) for `inline-block`, it is supported in all major browsers so it is a good and easy solution.

Moreover, giving a `display: block;` to `<td>` elements, will make `<td>`s act like `<tr>`

Here's the fiddle for demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v6puxbun/10/

In this way the table ***adapts to every resolution***.

I hope to be of help for someone.

Comment: @DaniSpringer - sorry but I can't help you here: I don't know why your navbar was temporarily messed up because you can't post your entire issue in comments. Please ask a new question and if you want comment the link here so I can try to help you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

text inside *tr* instead of *td* renders outside to table

```
<table><tr>abcd</tr></table>
```

will output

```
abcd
<table><tr></tr></table>
```

Basically you need *div* blocks with display set as inline-block.

```
<div>content1</div><div>content2</div><div>content3</div><div>content4</div>
<style>
  div {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 6px;
  }
</style>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ssreeram/wpnx202L/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I did not mean to put the text directly in `<tr>`s, in [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6puxbun/10/) the text is in `<td>`s.
The point is to show a table without a defined number of cells per row, using `<table>` element and `CSS` only. I'm about to update the question

Comment: Hey I tried applying that code like this: div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
} and it messed up (temporarily) my navbar! @CliffBurton